# Function Is Not Defined Error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call a function from componentDidMount which sets the State but keep coming across an error of

`Uncaught ReferenceError: setPanelState is not defined`

Below is the code...

```
export default class Patient extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);

    this.state = {
     PATIENT: [],
     COMPPROPS: [],
    };

    this.setPanelState = this.setPanelState.bind(this);
  }

    setPanelState(activity) {
          this.setState({COMPPROPS: [{compName:'Overview', compState:'Edit'}]});
    }

    componentDidMount() {   
       //handles chat commands and if the command is update patient the Overview panel should change to editable
       this.directLine.activity$
        .filter(function (activity) {
          return activity.type === 'event' && activity.value === 'Update Patient';
       })
       .subscribe(function (activity) {
         setPanelState(activity);   
       })
  }
```

I have tried make setPanelState a function outside of the class as opposed to a method but I get an error there as well.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using ES6 classes I assume you have it all set up.

Use arrow functions that bind **this** automatically

To learn more about arrow functions see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
.subscribe((activity) => {
    this.setPanelState(activity);   
})
```

Your component would look like this:

```
 export default class Patient extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);

    this.state = {
     PATIENT: [],
     COMPPROPS: [],
    };

    this.setPanelState = this.setPanelState.bind(this);
  }

    setPanelState(activity) {
          this.setState({COMPPROPS: [{compName:'Overview', compState:'Edit'}]});
    }

    componentDidMount() {   
       //handles chat commands and if the command is update patient the Overview panel should change to editable
       this.directLine.activity$
        .filter((activity) => {
          return activity.type === 'event' && activity.value === 'Update Patient';
       })
       .subscribe((activity) => {
         this.setPanelState(activity);   
       })
  }
```

Comment: This appears to have done it!  I seem to struggle with arrow functions and the use of this.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this.setPanelState(activity) and remember to maintian the context .As you are non ES6 arraow function . save the context outside var that=this and access that  variable inside

Answer (score 0):

In your `componentDidMount` method call `setPanelState` using `this.setPanelState`

you can also use a better format:

```
.subscribe(this.setPanelState)
```

If you put `setPanelState` outside the class and call it, it won't work,
unless it is defined inside another class where you can use `setState`.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
 this.setPanelState(activity)
```

at the end.

Comment: I have tried this but i get the error "Uncaught TypeError: this.setPanelState is not a function"